# Como setar um estado que está em uma constante com React com uma função

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
const [aulas, setAulas] = React.useState([{
 id:1,
 title: 'Aula 1',
 descricao: 'Matemática',
}, {
 id:2,
 title: 'Aula 2',
 descricao: 'Portugues',
}])
 function addAula(aula) {
  // aqui eu precisaria atualizar o estado de 'aulas' com uma nova aula.
 }
 return null
}
```

Porém eu não sei como eu poderia utilizar uma função para setar o state e atualizá-lo, apenas utilizando está função.

Se puderem em ajudar agradeço, estou iniciando em React e aprendendo os princípais ocnceitos de estado ainda.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres mostrar nessa página/app? o que faz `addAula`? como deve mostrar no html?

Answer (score 0):

A função `setAulas` deve ser a única forma de atualizar o state `aulas`.

Por exemplo, com `setAulas(novoObjetoAulas)`.

Eis aqui um exemplo completo, com demonstração no [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rodamaral/pen/bPaMEb?editors=0010):

```js
function Component() {
  const defaultObject = [
    {
      id:1,
      title: 'Aula 1',
      descricao: 'Matemática',
    },
    {
      id:2,
      title: 'Aula 2',
      descricao: 'Portugues',
    }
  ]

  const [aulas, setAulas] = React.useState(defaultObject)
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(3)

  function addAula(aula) {
    const atualizacao = [...aulas, aula]
    setAulas(atualizacao)
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    const aula = {
      id: id,
      title: 'Título qualquer que vc pode controlar',
      descricao: 'Descrição qualquer que vc pode controlar',
    }

    setId(id + 1)
    addAula(aula)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Adicionar aula
      </button>

      <ul>
      {
        aulas.map(item => {
          const {id, title, descricao} = item

          return (
            <li>
              <b>id</b> = {id}<br/>
              <b>title</b> = {title}<br/>
              <b>descricao</b> = {descricao}
            </li>
          )
        })
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```